# iOS and Google Firebase - How to do Notification Actions

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

**My Goal:**
Using Google Firebase Messaging, set up iOS Notification Actions

**Resources Referenced:**

- [Action Notification Tutorial](https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8/)
- [FCM - Message Format](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#http-request)
- [FCM - Message Format with Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messages-with-both-notification-and-data-payloads)
- [FCM - Handling Messages on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive#handling_messages)
- [iOS - Remote Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html)

**Question:**

I've looked through the above resources, but I still can't figure out how to set the category key for iOS, enabling notification actions. How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out as I was writing the question, and a Google search didn't help me, so hopefully this will help someone else.

I found the answer in this document: [FCM HTTP Protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support)

In the "Notification payload support" section, the parameter `click_action` says it "Indicates the action associated with a user click on the notification. Corresponds to category in the APNs payload."

So `click_action` == `aps.category`

Comment: Does this allow you to create action buttons in the notification itself?

Comment: Hi smileham, i have tried click_action, am setting this property in firebase while pushing notification, but it is not working for ios push notification. notification not showing any action when doing hardpress.

Comment: @smileham can you please send sample project for "click_action" type notifications. I tried, but I con't understand and I'm not getting any sample code from google. Can you send for me please....

Comment: You save my day!!!! click_action instead click-action as per plugin cordova-plugin-push!!! Thanks @smileham